# compliling sencha project to check error

Tags: ide, compilation, editor, extjs, sencha-architect

I am really new to sencha,  I am having tough time to identify whether the project has error or not . The only way is to check with firebug . I want to check if it has error or not before  running it.

Any idea? Any IDE for sencha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha  has their own IDE: http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/